# How can I make this python script work with the progress bar?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a code that is intended to check the proxies in a list from a folder and save the working list by their proxy type. However, after running the code, it seems that the proxies are not being checked, and the progress bar immediately shows 100% with a message indicating that all proxies have been processed at a rate of 802765.15 proxies per second. Can you help me figure out what I might be doing wrong?

```
import requests
import socks
import os
import threading
from queue import Queue
from tqdm import tqdm

# Function to test a proxy
def test_proxy(proxy, timeout, url, string):
    try:
        if proxy.startswith('http'):
            proxies = {"http": proxy, "https": proxy}
            r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, timeout=timeout)
            if string in r.text:
                return 'http'
        elif proxy.startswith('socks4'):
            socks4_proxy = proxy.replace('socks4://', '')
            socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4, socks4_proxy.split(':')[0], int(socks4_proxy.split(':')[1]))
            socket = socks.socksocket()
            socket.settimeout(timeout)
            socket.connect((url.split('//')[1], 80))
            if string in socket.recv(4096).decode():
                return 'socks4'
        elif proxy.startswith('socks5'):
            socks5_proxy = proxy.replace('socks5://', '')
            socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, socks5_proxy.split(':')[0], int(socks5_proxy.split(':')[1]))
            socket = socks.socksocket()
            socket.settimeout(timeout)
            socket.connect((url.split('//')[1], 80))
            if string in socket.recv(4096).decode():
                return 'socks5'
    except:
        pass
    return None

# Function to read the proxies from a file and test them
def check_proxies(file_name, timeout, url, string):
    proxies = []
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                proxies.append(line)
    results = {'http': [], 'https': [], 'socks4': [], 'socks5': []}
    for proxy in tqdm(proxies, desc=f"Checking {file_name}", unit=' proxies'):
        proxy_type = test_proxy(proxy, timeout, url, string)
        if proxy_type:
            results[proxy_type].append(proxy)
    for proxy_type, proxies in results.items():
        if proxies:
            with open(f"{proxy_type}.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write('\n'.join(proxies) + '\n')
    print(f"Finished checking {file_name}")

# Function to start checking the proxies in multiple threads
def check_proxies_multithreaded(file_names, timeout, url, string, num_threads=10):
    q = Queue()
    for file_name in file_names:
        q.put(file_name)
    threads = []
    for i in range(num_threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(q, timeout, url, string))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

# Function to get files from a directory
def get_files(dir_name):
    files = []
    for file_name in os.listdir(dir_name):
        if file_name.endswith('.txt'):
            files.append(os.path.join(dir_name, file_name))
    return files

# Function to be run by worker threads
def worker(q, timeout, url, string):
    while True:
        file_name = q.get()
        if file_name is None:
            break
        check_proxies(file_name, timeout, url, string)
        q.task_done()

# Sample usage
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dir_name = './proxies/'
    file_names = get_files(dir_name)
    timeout = 10
    url = 'https://www.google.com'
    string = 'feeling lucky'
    check_proxies_multithreaded(file_names, timeout=10, url='https://www.google.com', string='Google')
print("All files checked successfully!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to see a call to `check_proxies` within `check_proxies_multithreaded`

Comment: You are correct. The check_proxies function is not being called directly inside the check_proxies_multithreaded function. Instead, the worker function is called with the q parameter containing all the file names to be checked, and the worker function calls the check_proxies function with each file name in a loop.

But still, it is not checking the proxies, and the progress bar goes to 100% instantly.

Comment: Without reproducing the code myself, my random assumption is it's a "reference" mismatch of some sort. What you're passing might not be the objector reference you intend.